# Express 4.x only returning empty object from axios post request

Tags: express, axios, netlify-function

I'm trying to create a contact form in my react app. Every time I submit the form my Express server only receives the parameters that are empty.

Here is my server side code:

```
app.use(express.json());

router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // prints {name: "", subject: ""}
  res.status(200).send("Success");
});
```

My axios request:

```
axios.post(
  `http://localhost:9000/.netlify/functions/api/contact`,
  {
    name: name,
    emailAddress: email,
    subject: subject,
    message: message,
  },
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
);
```

It only prints `prints {name: "", subject: ""}` but I am filling out email address and message fields as well.

I have tried using bodyParser but it gives me deprecation notice as I am using Express 4.17.1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Axios drops undefined fields so you cannot see them on the server-side (undefined values do not convert to JSON), would you please post your network's payload too!

Comment: That's exactly what my issue was. The state wasn't getting updated and the variable stayed undefined. Resolved now. Thanks